# fread and fwrite in my below code is throwing segmentation fault?

Tags: c, file

I am trying to write integer number 12345 to my file name haha using fwrite and reading using fread but i am getting segmentation fault please help me to fix my code is below ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int num=12345;
    int dupnum;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("haha","w");
    fwrite(num,sizeof(int),1,fp);//here i m writing num in file
    fclose(fp);
    fp=fopen("haha","r");
    fread(dupnum,sizeof(int),1,fp);// reading from file and store in dupnum
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%d\n",dupnum);// why segmentation fault?
}
```

Comment: can you run in a debugger and see where the segfault is coming from? you can also then investigate the state of the variables. For instance, if the file fails to open, fp will be 0.

Comment: Your compiler is outdated to say the least.

Comment: Best to use `fp=fopen("haha","wb")/fopen("haha","rb");` when working with `fread()/fwrite()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fread` requires a pointer to the value you're storing in.

`fread(&dupnum,sizeof(int),1,fp)`

Also, you failed to check for a NULL file handle after calling `fopen`.  So a segmentation fault could happen for those reasons also.

Answer (score 1):

from man pages:

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);

size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

you're passing int, where `void *ptr` is needed. Change code to following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int num=12345;
    int dupnum;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("haha","w");
    fwrite((void*)&num,sizeof(int),1,fp);//pass address of num
    fclose(fp);
    fp=fopen("haha","r");
    fread((void*)&dupnum,sizeof(int),1,fp);// pass address of dupnum
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%d\n",dupnum);
}
```

Comment: but in case of array if i am not using & still i m getting output why?

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `fread` needs to be a pointer:

```
fread(&dupnum,sizeof(int),1,fp);
```

and the same for `fwrite`.